# Prove or disprove the system about $n$th power has only one solution $x=y=1$

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

$$\begin{cases}x^n+y^n=2\\x+y=2\end{cases}\;,\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,\;x,y\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;n>2$$

I have tried to show that $\displaystyle y'=-\frac{x^{n-1}}{y^{n-1}}=-1$
$$......$$
therefore $x=y=1$ is the only one solution.

Is there any method(s) to prove the question ?

It looks like Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: What type of numbers are $x,y$?

Comment: $x,y$ are real numbers

Comment: @recursiverecursion Um I think that's a little off topic. :) This is definitely _not_ related to Fermat's Theorem, it has $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @cwk709394 Can you show that the region is convex? Then the tangent line could not intersect it anywhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way: Make the change of variables $x= 1+a, y=1+b$.  Then the second equation gives $a = -b$.  Thus it remains to show that the following equation has only one solution $a=0$:
$$(1+a)^n + (1-a)^n -2 = 0$$

The LHS is a polynomial with all coefficients non-negative.  Hence it cannot have a positive root.  As the LHS is even, similarly there can be no negative root.  Hence $a=0$ is the only solution.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is what I want to find a simple way to solve the question.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is rigorous, but we can maximize the function $$f(x,y)=x+y$$ over the constraint $x^n+y^n=2$. Lagrange Multipliers gives $$(1,1)=\lambda (x^{n-1},y^{n-1})$$ Therefore we have $x=\pm y$ depending on the parity of $n$. Plugging into the equation we have $$2x^n=2\implies x,y=\pm1$$ which gives the values $(-2,0,2)$. Hence $2$ is the maximum of $x+y$ over that family of curves.

There cannot be another local maximum, so the only possibility is that $x+y$ increases without bound over the constraint. But it is not hard to see that this is not the case.

Comments about the validity of this argument would be appreciated. Specifically, I am not sure if it is valid to apply Lagrange over this non-compact region $x^n+y^n=2$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't tell you, I also tried this method. Sorry! /_\